# Customized input text box

Tags: html, css

Hi i want to make a customized input text box like this image:

[image]

I search many articles but found nothing to do this so please help me

Comment: Input type search with placeholder and the rest is CSS. What did you try so far?

Comment: i can't make that strange border

Comment: Border bottom 1px and then you can use :after and :before selectors to make the vertical borders

Comment: @progsource :before and :after do not work with input type text and some otrher form elements

Comment: Right - there was something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a new answer. But some modification to answer of @alvaro-menéndez to make it more compact and generic.

```css
div {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:50px;
}
input[type="text"] {
    width:300px;
    padding:10px;
    outline:0;
    border:0;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.preinput {
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:-1;
    display:block;
    bottom:-1px;
    left:-1px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
    border-right:1px solid #999;
    border-left:1px solid #999;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="preinput"></span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this little and simple jquery to add an element after your input:

```
$(".input").after("<span></span>");
```

and then you just have to style it like in this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g7cugzmv/3/)**

Edited: updated fiddle to put the element UNDER the input and move it slightly bottom and left so it will be visible even if input has a background-color

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a css background image on your input. Use a placeholder attribute for you "search".

HTML

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
```

CSS

```
input[type="search"]{
  background:url(your_image_path) left bottom no-repeat;
}
```